# Couldn't match expected type FullWeather with actual type m1 FullWeather

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-stack

I'm working with json code. And I can not extract from it the value due to an error in the type.And to get this error I'm using a function eitherDecode

Code part:

```
extractValues :: BSL.ByteString -> FullWeather
extractValues rawJSON = do
    let result  = eitherDecode rawJSON :: Either String FullWeather
    case result of
        Left problem -> return problem
        Right ok     -> return ok
```

Eroor:

```
  Couldn't match expected type ‘FullWeather’
       with actual type ‘m0 String’    
25        Left problem -> return problem

  Couldn't match expected type ‘FullWeather’
       with actual type ‘m1 FullWeather’
26        Right ok     -> return ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Three problems I can spot:

1. do-notation is for monadic values and is syntax sugar for applications of `(>>=)` and `(>>)`. Don't use do-notation for function that don't return a monadic value (like `IO a`, `[a]`, `Maybe a`...).  Outside of a do-notation the correct syntax is `let ... in ...`.
   I suggest following a Haskell tutorial like [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), which will teach you the correct usage of do-notation.
2. The function `return` has type `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`.
   **`return` is not a keyword**.
3. If your function returns a `FullWeather`, it can't return a string too. This is what `Either` or `Maybe` are for.
   Another thing you can do is throw an error.

There are 3 basic solutions we can use for this:

1. Throw an error in the case of a problem.

   ```
   extractValues :: BSL.ByteString -> FullWeather
   extractValues rawJSON =
       let result  = eitherDecode rawJSON :: Either String FullWeather
       in case result of
           Left problem -> error problem
           Right ok     -> ok
   ```
2. Return a `Maybe FullWeather` instead of `FullWeather`.

   ```
   extractValues :: BSL.ByteString -> Maybe FullWeather
   extractValues rawJSON =
       let result  = eitherDecode rawJSON :: Either String FullWeather
       in case result of
           Left problem -> Nothing
           Right ok     -> Just ok
   ```
3. Return an `Either String FullWeather` instead of `FullWeather`.

   ```
   extractValues :: BSL.ByteString -> Either String FullWeather
   extractValues = eitherDecode
   ```